# Casting an object to the same type & the effect on performance

Tags: c#, performance, casting

A question regarding the performance of casting an object to the same type (I know that sounds odd at first but let me put it in context)

```
public T Get<T>(string key) where T : class
{
     var objToReturn = (T)_cache[key];
     if (objToReturn != null)
     {
         return objToReturn;
     }
     return null;
}
```

The above is a snippet of code for attempting to get an object of type `T` out of a `CacheObject` where the type is strongly typed by the caller.

Know seeing as the type of the object is strongly typed, I am wondering about the line:

```
var objToReturn = (T)_chache[key];
```

Will this actually invoke a cast and convert instance in the cache to another instance and return that or will the types be found to be the same to the cast simply ignored.

I ask as the ability to cast will be useful in later development to the application that this cache is being used in for getting derived types but I don't want to breed in a potentially major performance hit early on.

Thoughts and thank you.

Comment: Based on the implementation of your method body, it can be refactored to a single line: `return _cache[key] as T;`.

Comment: @AndreasGrech: No, definitely not, because of the possibility of exceptions - see my reply to your comment in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cast you've shown is a "natural" reference type cast. It doesn't change anything about the object - it just ensures that the object is of an appropriate type (either the one you're casting to or a subclass). If the object is of the wrong type, an exception is thrown. No extra objects are created, or anything like that.

It's not free of course - but it would be rare for this to be a performance bottleneck.

It's not clear why you've got this code though:

```
if (objToReturn != null)
{
    return objToReturn;
}
return null;
```

Why not just use:

```
return objToReturn;
```

? That will behave exactly the same way. Then your entire method can be reduced to just:

```
public T Get<T>(string key) where T : class
{
    return (T) _cache[key];
}
```

EDIT: Note that you should *not* just use `as` instead, unless you really want values of the wrong type to silently be returned as `null`. For example:

```
cache[key] = new object();
string x = cache[key] as string; // x is null
string y = (string) cache[key]; // Exception
```

Comment: Jon, given the `T : class` constraint, is there a difference between using `(T)_cache[key]` or `_cache[key] as T` for this particular case?

Comment: The extra step is in there as will be putting in some handling if the object isn't found which hasn't been put in _yet_.
Thank you very much though, that settles the little niggle I had about this possibly getting in the way.

Comment: The `_cache[key] as T` version can not throw an exception, but the `(T)_cache[key]` version can.

Comment: @JohnWillemse: in this case, due to the `T : class` constraint, an exception won't be thrown.  Try it: `(Person)null`.

Comment: @AndreasGrech: Yes - in the face of an object of the wrong type, an `as` expression would return `null`, the cast will throw an exception.

Comment: @AndreasGrech: Casting `null` doesn't throw an exception, but casting a non-null reference *of the wrong type* does. Try `object x = new object(); string y = (string) x;`

Comment: @Andreas, I disagree. if `_cache[key]` is a class not of type `T`, or cannot be cast to type `T`, then an `InvalidCastException` will occur. However, using the `as` keyword, this would result in `null`.